# 2019-3 To Fill or Not to Fill (30 分) I cannot AC for I can't get through "last dist is exactly D"

Tags: c

the problem is:
With highways available, driving a car from Hangzhou to any other city is easy. But since the tank capacity of a car is limited, we have to find gas stations on the way from time to time. Different gas station may give different price. You are asked to carefully design the cheapest route to go.

Input Specification:
Each input file contains one test case. For each case, the first line contains 4 positive numbers: C
​max
​​  (≤ 100), the maximum capacity of the tank; D (≤30000), the distance between Hangzhou and the destination city; D
​avg
​​  (≤20), the average distance per unit gas that the car can run; and N (≤ 500), the total number of gas stations. Then N lines follow, each contains a pair of non-negative numbers: P
​i
​​ , the unit gas price, and D
​i
​​  (≤D), the distance between this station and Hangzhou, for i=1,⋯,N. All the numbers in a line are separated by a space.

Output Specification:
For each test case, print the cheapest price in a line, accurate up to 2 decimal places. It is assumed that the tank is empty at the beginning. If it is impossible to reach the destination, print The maximum travel distance = X where X is the maximum possible distance the car can run, accurate up to 2 decimal places.

Sample Input 1:
50 1300 12 8
6.00 1250
7.00 600
7.00 150
7.10 0
7.20 200
7.50 400
7.30 1000
6.85 300
Sample Output 1:
749.17
Sample Input 2:
50 1300 12 2
7.10 0
7.00 600
Sample Output 2:
The maximum travel distance = 1200.00

I use the greedy algorithm to solve this problem, first fill the tank to reach the nearest and cheapest station, if we don't have a station like that, then we may reach the destination or find a cheaper station in the range which we can reach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 500
typedef struct Station
{
    int distance;
    double price;
}Station_t;

int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const Station_t *pleft = (Station_t *)p1;
    const Station_t *pright = (Station_t *)p2;
    return pleft->distance < pright->distance ? -1 : pleft->distance > pright->distance;
}

int main()
{
    int capacity, totalDistance, davg, num, i;
    double usedMoney = 0;
    double usingC = 0;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &capacity, &totalDistance, &davg, &num);
    Station_t stas[N];
    for(i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%lf %d", &stas[i].price, &stas[i].distance);
    }
    stas[num].distance = totalDistance;
    stas[num].price = 0;
    qsort(stas, num, sizeof(Station_t), compare);
    if(stas[0].distance > 0)
    {
        printf("The maximum travel distance = 0.00");
        return 0;
    }
    Station_t *cur = stas, *next = &stas[1];
    while(cur != &stas[num - 1])
    {
        while(next->distance - cur->distance <= davg * capacity)
        {
            if(next->price < cur->price)
            {
                usedMoney += ((double)(next->distance - cur->distance - davg * usingC) / (double)davg) * cur->price;
                cur = next;
                if(cur == &stas[num - 1])
                    break;
                ++next;
            }
            else
            {
                if(next == &stas[num - 1])
                    break;
                ++next;
            }
        }
        if(cur == &stas[num - 1])
            break;
        usedMoney += (capacity - usingC) * cur->price;
        Station_t *temp = cur + 1, *fin = temp;
        while(fin != next)
        {
            if(fin->price < temp->price)
                temp = fin;
            ++fin;
        }
        usingC = capacity - (double)(temp->distance - cur->distance) / (double)davg;
        cur = temp;
    }
    if(totalDistance - cur->distance <= davg * capacity)
    {
        usedMoney += (double)(totalDistance - cur->distance) / (double)davg * cur->price;
        printf("%.2lf", usedMoney);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The maximum travel distance = %.2f", (float)(cur->distance + davg * capacity));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot get through a sample named "last dist is exactly D"

Comment: I suggest you read a little more about [the `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), especially what the comparison function should return.

Comment: Thank you, but I have test my qsort's result, it's just what I want, I know my code is not safe, I will  modify it. But I really want to know the meaning of "last dist is exactly D"

Comment: It's not about safe or unsafe, your comparison function is just plain wrong. It might work for you with your current input, but since your comparison function doesn't return the correct values other data might be sorted wrong.

Comment: Is it right? I just modify my code. But I still cannot AC

Comment: What does it mean when you say "I cannot AC"?

Comment: I means I cannot get through all the sample, its an  OJ problem

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison function has two problems:

1) Since the parameters are `const`, you need a pointer to `const`:

```
Station_t *pleft = (Station_t *)p1;
```

should be

```
const Station_t *pleft = p1;  // There is no need to cast
```

2) Is not enough to return `a > b`

Return value meaning:

```
<0 The element pointed by p1 goes before the element pointed by p2

0  The element pointed by p1 is equivalent to the element pointed by p2

>0 The element pointed by p1 goes after the element pointed by p2
```

You want:

```
return pleft->distance < pright->distance ? -1  : pleft->distance > pright->distance;
```

In this way it returns `-1`, `0` or `1` depending on `a < b`, `a == b` or `a > b`

Comment: Well `stas` is an array of `Station_t` elements, so that element-size it correct. And the return of the comparison function could be arranged as a simple subtraction (the returned value doesn't have to be exactly `-1`, `0` or `1`).

Comment: *The third parameter of qsort is the size of each element, not the size of the struct itself* Each element is a struct...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _And the return of the comparison function could be arranged as a simple subtraction_ - Right, but if the values in the integer array can be very large and very small (large magnitude but negative), then the subtraction can give signed arithmetic overflow.